# ros2 run gazebo_ros spawn_entity.py does not spawn urdf to gazebo

Tags: ros2, urdf, gazebo-11, spawn-model

I have the following AMR.urdf file

```xml
<robot
  name="AMR">
  <link name="base_footprint"/>

  <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="base_footprint"/>
    <child link="base_link"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.21" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  </joint>
  <link
    name="base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.001608 1.7089E-05 -0.037394"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="6.4118" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.056928"
        ixy="3.7366E-05"
        ixz="-0.000651"
        iyy="0.058024"
        iyz="-1.0318E-08"
        izz="0.091726" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.066666 0.003921 1 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <link
    name="lidar1">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.0025954 0.00035629 -0.010164"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.02126" />
      <inertia
        ixx="2.4452E-06"
        ixy="3.2059E-09"
        ixz="-6.3369E-07"
        iyy="3.8209E-06"
        iyz="-1.2436E-08"
        izz="4.3721E-06" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/lidar1.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0 0 0 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/lidar1.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="lidar_fixed1"
    type="fixed">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.14596 -0.10031 -0.03"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="lidar1" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="lidar2">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.0025954 -0.00035629 -0.010164"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.02126" />
      <inertia
        ixx="2.4452E-06"
        ixy="3.2059E-09"
        ixz="6.3369E-07"
        iyy="3.8209E-06"
        iyz="1.2436E-08"
        izz="4.3721E-06" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/lidar2.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0 0 0 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/lidar2.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="fixed_lidar2"
    type="fixed">
    <origin
      xyz="0.14596 0.10031 -0.03"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="lidar2" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="right_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-7.7318E-07 0.0060585 0.1"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.051919" />
      <inertia
        ixx="3.4107E-05"
        ixy="8.1903E-11"
        ixz="1.0913E-12"
        iyy="6.685E-05"
        iyz="-6.5152E-14"
        izz="3.4106E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/right_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.2470 0.2196 0.2196 0.79" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/right_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="right_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0.0025 -0.1013 -0.1"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="right_wheel" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 -1 0" />
    <!--<limit
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />-->
  </joint>
  <link
    name="left_wheel">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-7.7318E-07 -0.0059585 0.1"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.051919" />
      <inertia
        ixx="3.4107E-05"
        ixy="-8.1903E-11"
        ixz="-1.0913E-12"
        iyy="6.685E-05"
        iyz="-6.5152E-14"
        izz="3.4106E-05" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/left_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.2470 0.2196 0.2196 0.79" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/left_wheel.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="left_joint"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0.0025 0.1012 -0.1"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="left_wheel" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 -1 0" />
    <!--<limit
      effort="0"
      velocity="0" />-->
  </joint>
  <link
    name="caster_wheel_1">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.01689 -6.9165E-05 -0.03779"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.033984" />
      <inertia
        ixx="5.8935E-06"
        ixy="7.4544E-08"
        ixz="-7.5376E-07"
        iyy="1.1637E-05"
        iyz="2.6501E-08"
        izz="8.0534E-06" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/caster_wheel_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.2470 0.2196 0.2196 0.79" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/caster_wheel_1.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="caster_j1"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.096789 0.112 -0.1215"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="caster_wheel_1" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="caster_wheel_2">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.01689 -6.9165E-05 -0.03779"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.033984" />
      <inertia
        ixx="5.8935E-06"
        ixy="7.4544E-08"
        ixz="-7.5376E-07"
        iyy="1.1637E-05"
        iyz="2.6501E-08"
        izz="8.0534E-06" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/caster_wheel_2.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.2470 0.2196 0.2196 0.79" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/caster_wheel_2.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="caster_j2"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="-0.096789 -0.112 -0.1215"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="caster_wheel_2" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="caster_wheel_3">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="0.01689 6.9165E-05 -0.03779"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.033984" />
      <inertia
        ixx="5.8935E-06"
        ixy="7.4544E-08"
        ixz="7.5376E-07"
        iyy="1.1637E-05"
        iyz="-2.6501E-08"
        izz="8.0534E-06" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/caster_wheel_3.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.2470 0.2196 0.2196 0.79" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/caster_wheel_3.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="caster_j3"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0.082915 0.11207 -0.1215"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="caster_wheel_3" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
  </joint>
  <link
    name="caster_wheel_4">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.001608 1.7089E-05 -0.037394"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="6.4118" />
      <inertia
        ixx="0.056928"
        ixy="3.7366E-05"
        ixz="-0.000651"
        iyy="0.058024"
        iyz="-1.0318E-08"
        izz="0.091726" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/caster_wheel_4.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.2470 0.2196 0.2196 0.79" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0.05"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://AMR/meshes/caster_wheel_4.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
  </link>
  <joint
    name="caster_j4"
    type="continuous">
    <origin
      xyz="0.082915 -0.11207 -0.1215"
      rpy="0 0 0" />
    <parent
      link="base_link" />
    <child
      link="caster_wheel_4" />
    <axis
      xyz="0 0 1" />
  </joint>

</robot>
```

I try to spawn the URDF into gazebo by following the command.

`ros2 run gazebo_ros spawn_entity.py -entity AMR -file /home/dell/catkin_ros2_ws/src/AMR/urdf/AMR.urdf -x 0 -y 0 -z 0`

```
[INFO] [1694174949.993357631] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[INFO] [1694174949.993858462] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity XML from file /home/dell/catkin_ros2_ws/src/AMR/urdf/AMR.urdf
[INFO] [1694174949.994878476] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[INFO] [1694174949.995208811] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity
[INFO] [1694174949.999390617] [spawn_entity]: Calling service /spawn_entity
[INFO] [1694174950.277502483] [spawn_entity]: Spawn status: SpawnEntity: Successfully spawned entity [AMR]
```

Terminal show Successfully spawned but their is no robot spawn in gazebo
[image]

Comment: how do you solve the problem? (I can't make comment)

Comment: The answer is mentioned below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your model listed under Models/AMR in gazebo?

Have a look at ~/.gazebo/server-xxx/default.log

I have the same behavior with your file, because I don't have access to the STL files. Maybe this is the problem with your setup, too

```
(1694588803 305452291) [Wrn] [FuelModelDatabase.cc:313] URI not supported by Fuel [model://AMR/meshes/base_link.STL]  
(1694588803 305476776) [Wrn] [SystemPaths.cc:459] File or path does not exist [""] [model://AMR/meshes/base_link.STL]
```

Comment: Here is the link to the whole package that contains stl file in meshes foler [package](https://drive.google.com/file/d/11A23HdZHxQBuZPFqbhJfQXZ6qX21NUP9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Is your model listed under Models/AMR in gazebo?

Have a look at ~/.gazebo/server-xxx/default.log if you have the same problem

Comment: Thank you. Problem Solved :)